# Execute Code as Fast as Possible

Tags: json, node.js

I am using node.js with my WebStorm IDE to parse a large JSON file (~500 megabytes). Here is my code:

```
fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile('C:/Users/.../Documents/AAPL.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {

for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var hex = JSON.parse(data)[i]._source.layers.data["data.data"];

    var askPrice = parseInt(hex.substring(215, 239).split(":").reverse().join(""),16);
    var bidPrice = parseInt(hex.substring(192, 215).split(":").reverse().join(""),16);
    var symbol = hex.substring(156, 179);
    var timestamp = hex.substring(132, 155);
    var askSize = hex.substring(240, 251);
    var bidSize = hex.substring(180, 191);
    var price = String((+bidPrice+askPrice)/2);
    var realprice = price.slice(0, price.length - 4) + "." + price.slice(price.length - 4);

    function hex2a(hexx) {
        var hex = hexx.toString();
        var str = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2)
            str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
        return str;
    }
    if(JSON.parse(data)[i]._source.layers.data["data.len"] == 84 && realprice.length == 8 && +realprice <154 && +realprice >145) {
        console.log(i + " " + hex2a(symbol.replace(/:/g, "")) + " sold for " + realprice + " at " + parseInt(timestamp.split(":").reverse().join(""), 16));
    }
}

});
```

The problem I am running into however is that my IDE is parsing this file at an extremely slow speed, roughly 1 iteration a second. I do not think this is because I have a slow computer, for I have a high end rig with a core i7 7700k and a gtx 1070. I tried executing the code in the console with the same result. I tried trimming down the code and again I achieved the same speed:

```
 fs = require("fs");
 fs.readFile('C:/Users/Brandt Winkler Prins/Documents/AAPL.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {

for (i = 0; i < 12000; i++) {
    var hex = JSON.parse(data)[i]._source.layers.data["data.data"];

    var askPrice = parseInt(hex.substring(215, 239).split(":").reverse().join(""),16);
    var bidPrice = parseInt(hex.substring(192, 215).split(":").reverse().join(""),16);
    var price = String((+bidPrice+askPrice)/2);
    var realprice = price.slice(0, price.length - 4) + "." + price.slice(price.length - 4);

    if(+realprice <154 && +realprice >145) {
        console.log(realprice);
    }
}

});
```

How should I execute my code to get my data as fast as possible?

Comment: Do you really need to re-parse `JSON.parse(data)` the file every iteration? And do it twice.

Comment: That is the answer! I did that and it executed 12000 iterations in under a second! Amazing, thank you.

Comment: If the json is static you can just require it: var obj = require('path/to/json'). Saves you an async callback

Comment: So far it has nothing to do with WebStorm itself -- IDE does not execute your actual code -- it simply calls nodejs that executes it. Therefore I have removed the `webstorm` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running `JSON.parse(data)` every iteration, that might take quite some time for a 500MB json file.

The solution would be to move it out of the loop and reuse the parsed object:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
for (...
```